# how to toggle the symbols in html css js keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html, css

in the keyboard below i need to click shift and toggle the symbols and replace the numbers just like any other keyboard. how can i do that how to change the numbers to symbols via click?
i have already made a row of symbol buttons that i wanted to display when clicking but i cant so i need to know whats wrong with my code that i cant display the row that i made display none to activate from js ?
and a better way of toggling which is showing the symbols instead of numbers.

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const shift = document.getElementById('shift');
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('number');
const symbols = document.querySelectorAll('.symbol');
const button = document.getElementsByName('button');

btn.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('shift')) {
      console.log(btn.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgb(85, 4, 35);
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.keyboard {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn {
  font-size: large;
  width: 6vw;
  height: 8.3vw;
  border: none;
  background: url(./image/mobile_a_other_keyboard_20210609.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 24vw;
  margin-bottom: 0.9%;
  color: rgba(255, 250, 240, 0.925);
  background-position: 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:focus {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#shift {
  font-size: large;
  width: 9vw;
  background-position: 0 -8.5vw;
}

#backspace {
  font-size: large;
  width: 9vw;
  background-position: 0 -17vw;
}

.symbol {
  display: none;
}

.symbolDisplay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>keyboard-grid</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="keyboard">
      <button value="!" class="btn symbol">!</button>
      <button value="@" class="btn symbol">@</button>
      <button value="#" class="btn symbol">#</button>
      <button value="$" class="btn symbol">$</button>
      <button value="%" class="btn symbol">%</button>
      <button value="^" class="btn symbol">^</button>
      <button value="&" class="btn symbol">&</button>
      <button value="*" class="btn symbol">*</button>
      <button value="(" class="btn symbol">(</button>
      <button value=")" class="btn symbol">)</button><br>

      <button value="1" class="btn ">1</button>
      <button value="2" class="btn ">2</button>
      <button value="3" class="btn ">3</button>
      <button value="4" class="btn ">4</button>
      <button value="5" class="btn ">5</button>
      <button value="6" class="btn ">6</button>
      <button value="7" class="btn ">7</button>
      <button value="8" class="btn ">8</button>
      <button value="9" class="btn ">9</button>
      <button value="0" class="btn ">0</button><br>
      <button value="q" class="btn">q</button>
      <button value="w" class="btn">w</button>
      <button value="e" class="btn">e</button>
      <button value="r" class="btn">r</button>
      <button value="t" class="btn">t</button>
      <button value="y" class="btn">y</button>
      <button value="u" class="btn">u</button>
      <button value="i" class="btn">i</button>
      <button value="o" class="btn">o</button>
      <button value="p" class="btn">p</button><br>
      <button value="a" class="btn">a</button>
      <button value="s" class="btn">s</button>
      <button value="d" class="btn">d</button>
      <button value="f" class="btn">f</button>
      <button value="g" class="btn">g</button>
      <button value="h" class="btn">h</button>
      <button value="j" class="btn">j</button>
      <button value="k" class="btn">k</button>
      <button value="l" class="btn">l</button><br>
      <button id="shift" value="shift" class="btn shift">shift</button>
      <button value="z" class="btn">z</button>
      <button value="x" class="btn">x</button>
      <button value="c" class="btn">c</button>
      <button value="v" class="btn">v</button>
      <button value="b" class="btn">b</button>
      <button value="n" class="btn">n</button>
      <button value="m" class="btn">m</button>
      <button id="backspace" value="backspace" class="btn">back</button>



    </div>
  </div>






  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: You have a Keyboard, with keys "A,B,C,D,E,..." and Key "Show Special Characters" (this your SHIFT), when user click on "Show special characters" this must replace "A,B,C,D,E,..." with "1,2,3,4,&,%,$"  did I understand it well or misunderstand?

Comment: S.wasta yes thats what i cant figure out how to do?

Comment: And by clicking shift i mean the shift key in the virtual keyboard not my shift button in my device